# loader problem

Tags: jquery, image, preloader, image-preloader

I want to know whether it is posible to have loader which will run till all the images in the page been loaded to the page . I have a website http://ranjoy.athost.net/ which is having some png large size images, i want all the images to load before the animation start .... plz help

Comment: Have you thought about loading the images that are not visible in the beginning on demand via AJAX? I think that would save a lot of loading tiime.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this technique

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/

Will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right this would do the job

```
$( "img" ).ready(function(){
 //code to start animation 
});
```

edit: a callback is used and is called when all the images in the page have loaded. If you wanted to wait only until certain images have laoded you could try this

```
$( "img.anim" ).ready(function(){
 //code to start animation 
});
```

and give all your animation images a class of anim like this

```
<img src="whatever.png" class="anim" />
```